# Creating and argsorting a Python-numpy array with a structured dtype leaks memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory, memory-leaks, windows-7-x64

This week I've been hunting a memory leak in my Python application that has been causing MemoryErrors, and have managed to distill the logic that appears to be causing it down to 20 lines. The following snippet of code consumes steadily increasing amounts of memory when run (even after the calls to gc.collect every 5000th iteration), as observed from the task manager. Why? Is this a bug in numpy?

```
import gc
import numpy as np

while True:
    names = ["POH"] + \
        ["Head %d Really Long Data Field Name With Many Words" % i for i in xrange(200)]
    formats = [">f"] + [">I"] * 200
    offsets = range(0, 804, 4)

    dt = np.dtype({"names": names, "formats": formats, "offsets": offsets})
    array = np.zeros((1000,), dt)

    sortedIndices = np.argsort(array, order=["POH"])

    n += 1
    if n % 1000 == 0:
        print n
        if n % 5000 == 0:
            gc.collect()
```

I am running numpy 1.11.0 with Python 2.7.11 on 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: I like answering structured array stuff, but I'm not sure I even want to touch this.  You are constructing a pathological dtype, and performing an `ordered` argsort.   What if you take the `dt` definition out of the loop?  The `zeros` creation, leaving only the `argsort`?  What if the dtype is much smaller, or the names shorter?  Finally have you searched the `numpy` github issues?

Comment: Could this bug issue apply?  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6250.  `argsort` must be doing a lot record compares.  Also https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5901

Comment: Does the problem depend on the sort `kind`?

Comment: I deliberately made the dtype large to make the leak easier/quicker to detect from process memory usage, and to simulate the similarly complex dtype in my actual use case. (I haven't been able to find any up-to-date memory checking tools that detect the leak) It does not appear to depend on the sort `kind`. None of the existing bug reports sound like my problem. The first linked issue seems similar, but has already been resolved in (I think) 1.10.0. I mostly just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong on my end before reporting a bug in numpy.